# Meta: Make [off-topic] a synonym of [scope]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request, meta

The [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) tag on Meta.SO seems to be the authoritative tag regarding on-topic vs. off-topic questions. From the excerpt,

> Use this tag when examining what is on-topic or off-topic, and why.

The [on-topic](/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag has already been folded into this one, but the [off-topic](/questions/tagged/off-topic) tag remains. Can someone fold it in as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created the [custom-close-reasons](/questions/tagged/custom-close-reasons) tag (to match the Meta SE site) for those questions that were talking about the off-topic close reasons and not about the scope of the site.

The rest have been merged into [scope](/questions/tagged/scope) and a synonym has been created.